# storing the selected value of a select control in a php variable

Tags: php

Lets say i have an html control of the form

`<input name='options' value='one' title='ABC'>`
  `<input name='options' value='two' title='XYZ'>`

The user selects one of the options. How can i store the selected option in a variable on the same page without using the $_POST. This form posts onto another page.

Comment: If the user can select only one of the options, you probably should use a `select` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP only works by the browser sending a request (as GET or POST) to the server and the server then executing the program ("page"), sending back the HTML (or whatever produced) to interpretation by the browser.

This means, a PHP page can only access "HTML variables" which got sent to it (from a form or a link), not anything the user enters on the produced HTML page without sending.

You may want to use client-side scripting (i.e. JavaScript) to do that, or think about your "page model" (i.e. which page does what).

PS: Your `<input>` element should have a `type` attribute, too.

Comment: If an input element has no type, it is a text field by default.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Yes, but then it does not make sense to have two of them with the same name and different values. I thought this should be `type="radio"`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use either $_POST or $_GET. This is a standard approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible as PHP is parsed BEFORE there's something in your browser.

Why would someone do that? (I'm just wondering)